# "Menu of services include" or "...includes"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm not sure about the pluralization here:

> menu of services includes

or

> menu of services include

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete sentence would be helpful for context but nevertheless ...

If the menu is singular then it would be "includes":

> The menu of services includes A, B and C.

Note that you could also write something like:

> A wide menu of services is available, including A, B and C.

Note: 'is' not 'are' in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you want includes. The subject, "menu", is singular: A menu includes. You wouldn't say, a menu include. So the noun phrase "of services" is merely misleading here.

If you were talking about services, you'd use the plural: services include. But you only have one menu in this sentence.